# How to insert record to database from the model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Profiles controller:

```
def change_cover
    @cover_name = params[:cover]

    Profile.cover_name(@cover_name, session[:username])
end
```

My Model:

```
def self.cover_name(is, username)
    Profile.new(:cover_name => is, :username => username).save
end
```

But it prints the next error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: cover_name):
app/models/profile.rb:7:in `cover_name'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:22:in `change_cover'
```

So, how can I insert it?

Comment: please show your `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: @Зелёный http://pastebin.com/rFYLLZ9A

Comment: please post in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

This error generates because your database table assuming your module has default settings, `profiles` doesnot have a column called `cover_name`

You can do two things to test this

1 ) Check your DB directly. Example code in mysql

```
 `desc profiles`
```

2 ) Login to your rails console and type

```
`Profile.new`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create Profile with attribute profile_name and since profile has no attribute like profile_name it throws this error,

I guess you wanted to something like

```
def self.cover_name(covername, username)
    ProfileCover.create(cover_name: covername, username: username)
end
```

Also, I see no association in your schema.rb, but I guess the profile cover should somehow be associated to your profile so you should do a migration creating one

```
rails g migration AddProfileToProfileCovers profile:belongs_to
```

In profile_cover.rb do

```
belongs_to :profile
```

In profile.rb

```
has_one :provile_cover
```

and update your method

```
def cover_name(covername, username)
    self.profile_cover.create(cover_name: covername, username: username)
end
```

and call it with `@profile.cover_name(covername, username)`

or the other way around (not recommended)

```
def self.cover_name(covername, username, profile)
    profile.profile_cover.create(cover_name: covername, username: username)
end
```

and call it with `Profile.cover_name(covername, username, profile)`

Comment: `def change_cover
    @cover_name = params[:cover]
    @profile.cover_name(@cover_name, session[:username])
end`

`def cover_name(is, username)
    self.profile_cover.create(cover_name: is, username: username)
end`

But it prints the next error:

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'cover_name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:22:in 'change_cover'`

Comment: well, you should define `@profile` in your controller, probably with something like `@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])`, if you are editing profile, or create a new profile with `@profile = Profile.new; @profile.save` # `@profile = Profile.create`